# SQL - Remove most recent date and note from string

Tags: sql, string

I am working with a table in SQL that has a field that gets appended each time a note is added. For reporting purposes, I need just the latest date/note and honestly have no idea where to start. I've done functions to pull out just numbers, and character indexes, etc - but those don't seem to apply given the field (in this example) has 3 like values and I just need the latest one.

An example of field date:

```
3/4/2020 1:06:30 PM by username
Notes #1

3/4/2020 1:06:41 PM by username
Notes #2

**3/12/2020 1:12:27 PM by username
Can enter a new note here**
```

I just need to extract the bolded note. My report is populating from a stored procedure, so I need to figure out the SQL code to extract just the latest note. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results. I assume instead of "a field that gets appended each time a note is added" you meant "a row that gets appended..." Is the sample data you added here all in a single column (like the date and text is stored in the same column)?

Comment: The data is stored in a singular column per record. And yes, as a field gets updated, that column is updated so the data shown is the 'Notes' column for just one record.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple database design issues going on here which you may already realize.

1. You should not have multiple records (Notes) in the same record.
2. You should not have multiple fields (Date, UserName, Comment) in the same field.

I am going to assume you are using SQL Server. If not, this solution should be able to be adapted to your platform. I took the liberty to add an ID column called **SomeID**.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Notes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Notes;

CREATE TABLE #Notes
(
    SomeID INT
  , Note VARCHAR(4000)
);

INSERT INTO #Notes
VALUES
(1, '3/4/2020 1:06:30 PM by username
Notes #1

3/4/2020 1:06:41 PM by username
Notes #2')
, 

(2
 , '3/4/2020 1:16:30 PM by username
Notes #1

3/4/2020 1:23:41 PM by username
Notes #2

3/4/2020 1:32:51 PM by username
Notes #3');

SELECT   
         *
FROM     (
             SELECT
                  y.SomeID
                , CONVERT(DATETIME2, y.NoteDateText)            AS NoteDate
                , REPLACE(y.Line1, y.NoteDateText + ' by ', '') AS UserName
                , y.Comment
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y.SomeID
                                     ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME2, y.NoteDateText) DESC
                                    ) AS RowNumber
             FROM (
                      SELECT
                           x.SomeID
                         , LEFT(x.Line1, PATINDEX('%by%', x.Line1) - 2) AS NoteDateText
                         , x.Line1
                         , x.Line2                                      AS Comment
                      FROM (
                               SELECT
                                           SomeID
                                         , LEFT(value, PATINDEX('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%', value) - 1)               AS Line1
                                         , RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - PATINDEX('%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '%', value) - 1) AS Line2
                                         , value
                               FROM        #Notes
                               CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(Note, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '~'), '~')
                           ) x
                  ) y
         ) z
WHERE z.RowNumber = 1
```

The basic ideas is to split up the notes into individual records using the [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table-valued function. Since STRING_SPLIT() only works with a separator of a singular character and your note records seem to be separated by two sets of carriage return (CHAR(13)) and line feeds (CHAR(10)) I replaced them with a '~'. You should use some character that won't be in the text of your Note records. Now that I have the Notes separated I can pick apart each Note into proper fields of NoteDate, UserName, and Comment using string manipulation functions.

Finally, I used the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to sort the Notes in descending order by NoteDate for each value of SomeID so I can then select only the first row for each SomeID.

I certainly could have condensed this further and not used as many levels of subqueries, but I want to show the progression and hopefully make it easier to follow. Also, I tried to put this in SQL Fiddle or dbfiddle, but I kept getting the following error.

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

This code works in SQL Server Management Studio on SQL Server 2016 or higher.

Here is an alternative approach I got to work on a SQL Server 2012 server based on this blog [post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Notes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Notes;

CREATE TABLE #Notes
(
    SomeID INT
  , Note VARCHAR(4000)
);

INSERT INTO #Notes
VALUES
(1, '3/4/2020 1:06:30 PM by username
Notes #1

3/4/2020 1:06:41 PM by username
Notes #2')
, (2
 , '3/4/2020 1:16:30 PM by username
Notes #1

3/4/2020 1:23:41 PM by username
Notes #2

3/4/2020 1:32:51 PM by username
Notes #3');


SELECT
      x6.SomeID
    , x6.NoteDate
    , x6.UserName
    , x6.Comment
FROM  (
          SELECT
               x5.SomeID
             , x5.NoteDate
             , x5.UserName
             , x5.Comment
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x5.SomeID
                                  ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME2, x5.NoteDate) DESC
                                 ) AS RowNumber
          FROM (
                   SELECT
                        x4.SomeID
                      , CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(x4.SingleNote, PATINDEX('%by%', x4.SingleNote) - 2))              AS NoteDate
                      , SUBSTRING(
                                     x4.SingleNote
                                   , PATINDEX('%by%', x4.SingleNote) + 3
                                   , PATINDEX('%' + CHAR(10) + '%', x4.SingleNote)
                                     - (PATINDEX('%by%', x4.SingleNote) + 3)
                                 )                                                                               AS UserName
                      , RIGHT(x4.SingleNote, LEN(x4.SingleNote) - PATINDEX('%' + CHAR(10) + '%', x4.SingleNote)) AS Comment
                   FROM (
                            SELECT
                                        x2.SomeID
                                      , x2.Note
                                      , LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'varchar(8000)'))) AS [SingleNote]
                            FROM        (
                                            SELECT
                                                 SomeID
                                               , Note
                                               , CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>'
                                                      + REPLACE(
                                                                   Note
                                                                 , CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                                                                 , '</RowData><RowData>'
                                                               ) + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x1
                                            FROM #Notes
                                        )                            x2
                            CROSS APPLY x1.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
                        ) x4
               ) x5
      ) x6
WHERE x6.RowNumber = 1;
```

It is ugly, I know. And I am not sure I can fully explain every line. I am just trying to offer a solution as a method of learning myself. This query is a perfect example of why good database design matters.

Comment: Thanks! I realize there's a database design issue! Not my database, I just work within it. My life would be MUCH easier if the issues you outlined did not exist. Thanks for your input and I'll report back.

Comment: I completely understand having to work within the framework of what exists. Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Isaac - not yet. This customer is on 2012 and Cross_Apply doesn't work. Assuming I can use Inner Join instead, but haven't gotten there yet.

Comment: I don't think CROSS APPLY is the problem with my solution, but STRING_SPLIT() would most certainly be. You can achieve something similar using XQuery (I think that is what it is called) like [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/). I was able to get it to work on a SQL Server 2012 server I have, but not on dbfiddle.